# Redshift, casting of a decimal value is not rounding off

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a reshift table, which has a decimal column of **(38, 29)**, but the *original data's maximum Integer part is 6 and scale is 12* i.e Decimal **(18,12)**. But the table is created using the max precision and scale. So all the data in that has `0's` at the end of the scale part as padding.

For Example:

```
12345.123456789112300000000000000000000
```

All the data in the table is like the above example.

Now I'm retrieving the data from the table using the below query.

```
select cast(column as decimal(30,6)) from table;
```

The output I'm getting is

```
12345.123456
```

But when I try the below query

```
select cast(12345.123456789112300000000000000000000 as decimal(30,6)) from table;
```

The output I'm getting is

```
12345.123457
```

I want to know why this is happening. when I cast the column in the table, it is not rounding off to its highest value, it is just truncating.
But when I try with the decimal itself it is truncating and it is rounding off.

I also want to how to achieve the second query's result in the table itself.

Answer (score 0):

So this comes down to when is a cast not a cast.  If I cast and integer to an int it does nothing.  Casting a varchar to a shorter varchar is nearly as simple as long as the data fits.  Casting a decimal to a lower scale decimal is also a simplistic operation as it is not changing the data type, just some attribute of it (scale).  What you desire is that Redshift implicitly ROUNDS the values when you make this conversion and it is not. (I'll let the database philosophers debate if this is a bug or not.)

Here's a simple example to highlight this:

```
drop table if exists goo;
create table goo (rownum int, num decimal(30,6));
insert into goo select 1, 12345.123456789112300000000000000000000::text;
insert into goo select 2, 12345.123456789112300000000000000000000::decimal(38,29);
insert into goo select 3, 12345.123456789112300000000000000000000::double;
select rownum, num::text from goo;
```

In all 3 of these examples there is an implicit cast to the data type of the column 'num' in the table.  However you can see that what is getting into the table is different.  Lots of experiments can be set up like this.  (Note that I'm casting the result to text to avoid any bench precision changes.)

The answer in your case is to explicitly ROUND() the value.